# Javascript Array not being filled

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So i'm trying to self learn HTML and Jscript but i cannot figure out for the life of me what i've did wrong in this piece of code, its a drop down question list that asks the user what fruits they like, and their asking to make 9 answers, so this script is to capture those answers and store them in an array but when it breaks outside the loop the last alert does not show, so i can see the array is not actually getting filled.

I used the alerts for bug checking :)

```
 <script>
      function submitInfo(passed){
           var Fruit = [];
           var myForm = passed+"Form";

           //alert("here start"+" "+document.getElementById(myForm).length+" "+myForm);
           for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById(myForm).length; i++) {
                //alert("in loop");
                var myFruit = passed+"Input"+i;
                //alert(myFruit+" "+document.getElementById(myFruit).value);

                Fruit.push(document.getElementById(myFruit).value);
                // var Fruit[i] = document.getElementById(myFruit).value;
                alert(Fruit[i]);
           }
           alert(Fruit[i]);
      }
 </script>
```

Thank you in advance for any help, it is appreciaed

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your HTML as well please?

Comment: try to declare `var Fruit = new Array()`

Comment: Try using [link](http://jsfiddle.net/) to explain things better

Answer (score 2):

The array is being populated correctly, it's just that you are not testing it correctly.

The reason is because after your loop, `i` will be equal to `document.getElementById(myForm).length`. So when you use it to access the `Fruit` array you are accessing an index which has not been populated. You can prove this by doing the following after the loop:

```
alert(i);
```

For example, if `document.getElementById(myForm).length` is say `5`. Your loop will run for `0..4` but it will still increment to `5` prior to deciding to break the loop (it has to increment it so it can evaluate the condition). At this point you will have 5 items in your array (indices 0-4). Then when you call the last alert, `i = 5`, but `Fruit[5]` does not exist.

If you were to change the last alert (after the loop) to `Fruit[0]` it should display the first item. You could also do `console.log(Fruit)` and check the console for the full contents of the array.

[This may help to demonstrate it better.](http://jsfiddle.net/4H8L4/)

Comment: Hi thank you very much, but it still refuses to work, it wont show up the last alert it just exits after it reaches 10

Comment: @NewbietoJedi: Prove it. Create a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) that shows your problem in action. Maybe you have console errors? Perhaps you are trying to access an element with and id that doesn't exist? That would cause you problems